# Autofac RegisterType with Parameters

Tags: autofac

Please could someone advise on how I go about registering a class with a parameter passed at runtime

```
public interface ITabContentSending
{
    TabType TheTabType { get; set; }
    int? OrderId { get; set; }
}
public class TabContentSending : ITabContentSending
{
    public TabType TheTabType { get; set; }
    public int? OrderId { get; set; }

    public TabContentSending(int orderId)
    {
        TheTabType = TabType.Table;
        OrderId = orderId;
    }

}
```

My current effort (which are clearly wrong)

```
            builder.RegisterType<TabContentSending>()
            .As<ITabContentSending>()
            .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(int) && p.Name == "orderId",
                (p, c) => "OrderId"));
```

Results in a runtime Error of:

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>   An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Int32)' on type 'TabContentSending'. ---> Input string was not in a correct format. (See inner exception for details.)

Comment: please share the details of the `DependencyResolutionException`, the answer is usually there.

Comment: Please improve the title of your question.

Comment: Updated as per suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass the parameter value during type registration (as in your code sample), you can use various of possibilities: named, typed and resolved parameters. If you want to stay with resolved one, as in your example, the second parameter of `ResolvedParameter` object should be a lamba expression returning value you want to use when resolving an instance. So, because `orderId` is of integer type, it should look like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<TabContentSending>()
  .As<ITabContentSending>()
  .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(int) && p.Name == "orderId",
    (p, c) => 1)); // the value of "1" would be injected
```

In your example you tried to inject a string value "OrderId" to integer `orderId` parameter.

But, if you want to pass the value of `orderId` in runtime, you should register your type as usual, without `.WithParameter` part, and then, instead of injecting `ITabContentSending tabContentSending`, you should inject `Func<int, ITabContentSending> tabContentSendingFunc`. Doing so, instead of injecting an instance, you inject a delegate, which allows you to create instances of `ITabContentSending` and pass proper value of `orderId` parameter:

```
var orderId = 1;
var instance = tabContentSendingFunc(orderId);
```

You can find futher information about passing parameters during registration [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html), and about parameterized instantiation [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b).

Comment: thank you for your answer - works a charm, but raises further question for me. In my learning app the orderId value is set before the call that uses tabContentSendingFunc. main question ammended to show the code. Its most likely incorrect due to my lack of knowledge