# Passing constructor parameter throught multiple objects while resolving in AutoFac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, parameter-passing, autofac, constructor-injection

i have difficulties getting my registration in AutoFac done.

Let`s say i have the following classes

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
public Foo(string test, IBar bar) {}
}

class Bar : IBar 
{
public Bar(bool someFlag) {}
}
```

The issue I'm having now is that i don't know how to set this boolean 'someFlag' while resolving.
I am only able to create these objects and fill in the flag while resolving, not while registering the classes.
Note: This is just an easy example to show the problem. In my case there are half a dozen classes in between Foo and Bar.

Can anyone please help me?

I know how to fill a parameter directly like the string 'test'. But I don`t understand how i pass the boolean through Foo to Bar.

Comment: Do it after in a method call, there's nothing wrong with that. Or don't register, you don't need DI. I think you're placing too much emphasis on forcing the design principal rather than a design that works properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autofac RegisterType with Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305680/autofac-registertype-with-parameters)

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html)